# not able to get values from database and updating values to the database

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

into schooling entry form, I am not able to get value of employee_id from post.
I did Print_r for $employee_id, blank output is rendered.
Also if allocated static value to $employee_id, $sum contains only value posted through the form, instead it should show the value from input form plus value from existing value available in database.

```
<?php
$get = db_query("SELECT field_employee_id_value FROM field_data_field_employee_id ORDER BY field_employee_id_value ASC");

$getempnames = db_query("SELECT field_employee_id_value FROM field_data_field_employee_id ORDER BY field_employee_id_value ASC");


if(isset($_POST['apply'])){

    $sql = db_query("SELECT COUNT(id) as count_id FROM schooling WHERE employee_id = '$_POST[employee_id]' AND claim_year = '$_POST[claim_year]'");

    $row = $sql->fetchAssoc();

    if('1' == $row['count_id']){

        $sqlupdate = db_query("UPDATE schooling SET limit_amount = '".$_POST['limit_amount']."' WHERE employee_id = '$_POST[employee_id]'");

         echo "Schooling limit updated to user ";

        } elseif ('0' == $row['count_id']){

        $sqlinsrt = db_query("INSERT INTO schooling (employee_id, limit_amount, claim_year) VALUES ('".$_POST["employee_id"]."','".$_POST["limit_amount"]."','".$_POST["claim_year"]."')" );

        echo "Schooling limit applied to user";

        } else{
            echo "Already Applied schooling limit";
        }

    }

if(isset($_POST['save'])){

    $employee_id = $_POST['employee_id'];

    $claim_amount = $_POST['claim_amount'];

    $claim_year = $_POST['claim_year'];

    $sqlchkemp = db_query("SELECT COUNT(id) as count_id FROM schooling WHERE employee_id = '$employee_id' AND claim_year = '$claim_year'");

    $empavailable = $sqlchkemp->fetchAssoc();


    if('1' == $empavailable['count_id']){

        $getlimit = db_query("SELECT limit_amount FROM schooling WHERE employee_id = '$employee_id' AND claim_year = '$claim_year'");

        $limit = $getlimit->fetchAssoc();

            $getemptotalclaim = db_query("SELECT claim_amount FROM schooling 
                        WHERE employee_id = '$employee_id' AND claim_year = '$claim_year'");

            $emptotalclaim = $getemptotalclaim->fetchAssoc();

            $totalclaimed = array_sum($emptotalclaim);

            $availability = $limit['limit_amount'] - $_POST['claim_amount'];

        $sum = $totalclaimed['claim_amount'] + $claim_amount;


            if ($sum <= $limit['limit_amount']){

                $sqlinsert = db_query("UPDATE schooling SET claim_amount = '$sum' WHERE employee_id = '$employee_id'");

                    echo "values updated successfuly";

                }

            else{
                    echo "limit is over, you can avail total amount ".$availability." as per  ".$limit['limit_amount']." alloted"; 
            }
    }

    else{
        echo "employee schoolig limit is not set";
    }
}

?>


<html>
<body>  
<form id='applylimit' action='' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset>
<label>Apply Schooling Limit amount to Employee</label>

<label for='employee_id'>Employee Id</label>    
<select name='employee_id'>
 <option value="0">Please Select</option>
      <?php
        while($row = $getempnames->fetchAssoc())
        {
      ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo($row['field_employee_id_value'])?>">
            <?php echo($row['field_employee_id_value']) ?>
        </option>
      <?php
        }               
      ?>
    </select>

<label for='limit_amount'>Limit Amount</label>
<input type='number' name='limit_amount' id='limit_amount' maxlength="50" />

<label for='claim_year'>Claim Year</label>

<select type='number' name='claim_year' id='claim_year' maxlength="50">
    <option value="2018-19">2018-19</option>
    <option value="2019-20">2019-20</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" name="apply">Apply</button>

</fieldset>
</form>

<form id='schoolingentry' action='' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>

<fieldset>
<label for='employee_id'>Employee Id </label>
<select name='employee_id'>
 <option value="0">Please Select</option>
      <?php
        while($rowemp = $get->fetchAssoc())
        {
        ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo($row['field_employee_id_value'])?>" >
            <?php echo($rowemp['field_employee_id_value']) ?>
        </option>
        <?php
        }
      ?>
    </select>


<label for='claim_amount'>Claim Amount</label>
<input type='number' name='claim_amount' id='claim_amount' maxlength="50" />

<label for='claim_year'>Claim Year</label>
<select name='claim_year' id='claim_year' maxlength="50">
    <option value = "2018-19">2018-19</option>
    <option value = "2019-20">2019-20</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" name="save">save</button>

</fieldset>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you use drupal framework?

Comment: yes, and i did this coding for testing purpose as a seperate module and inserted some php code

Answer (score 0):

word of warning, do not put anything submitted from a $_POST straight into a database query. You should sanitize it all by passing in the parameters.

e.g.
$result = db_query('SELECT n.name FROM users n WHERE n.name = :name', array(':name' => $name));

If the first query isn't returning any results, it's likely those two parameters you are passing into the string are not what you expect, or not valid. Try echoing out the two variables, then running the SQL query manually.

Or if you want Drupal to be a bit more verbose, wrap it in a exception catcher..

e.g.

catch (\PDOException $e) {
  $error = $e->getMessage();